# SQL Parameters Not Accessing In The .CS Form

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, entity-framework-4.1

We are using ASP.NET MVC 3.0 code-first Linq-to-Sql.

Initially we build all the tables, stored procedures etc.. it's working fine.

I updated the stored procedure in the SQL Server database directly by adding 3 new parameters. But I am facing the problem that I can't access those new 3 parameters in my .CS file.

At initial stage when we build those stored procedures there are 2 parameters those are retrieving fine.

Here is the code

```
protected databasecontext db;

public List<databasecontextname(.dbml file)> GetList()
{
   var x = db.storedprocedurename(parameters here)
}
```

Comment: Do you get an exception when trying to access the new parameters?

Comment: @Joshua Drake - Not getting any exception its going good but paramerters are not accessing

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution we have to update the .dbml file with the latest stored procedure because the application will take the .dbml context.